# How to add some columns from table and show them in another

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am trying to create storage program.

I have 3 DataGridViews([Picture of menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Md9.png)), 1 is for Items, 2 is for Delivery notes and 3 is for showing Items which Delivery note contains([DbModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRF4R.png)).

I want to add like 5 items from ItemsInStock to DeliveryNote and when I click on that DeliveryNote show the items that I add in DataGridView.

Then in the next DeliveryNote add 7 items and show them when I click on DeliveryNote and like that...

I was trying to do that with this code but it didn't work and I'm not sure if I'm on right way. I´m using Entity framework too.

```
string sqlString = "SELECT * FROM [ItemsInStock] " + "INNER JOIN [DeliveryNote] on [DeliveryNote].[Id] = [ItemsInStock].[DeliveryNoteId]";

ShowItemsInDeliveryNoteDgw.DataSource = sqlString.ToList();
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to display?

Comment: I mean which table? DeliveryNote or ItemsInStock?

Comment: I want display DeliveryNote which shoud contains or refer to some items which are created in ItemsInStock table.

Answer (score 0):

Change your SQL Query to

```
SELECT [DeliveryNote].* FROM [ItemsInStock] + INNER JOIN [DeliveryNote] on [DeliveryNote].[Id] = [ItemsInStock].[DeliveryNoteId]
```

Answer (score 0):

To display DeliveryNote which shoud contains or refer to some items which are created in ItemsInStock table use this query:

```
SELECT DeliveryNote.* FROM [DeliveryNote] INNER JOIN [ItemsInStock] on 
[DeliveryNote].[Id] = [ItemsInStock].[DeliveryNoteId]
```